# How do I define the JNI method signature of a generic class?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a base class defined in java. I would like to call a native method like so:

```
public class Base<T>
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        nativeDoSomething();
    }

    private native void nativeDoSomething();
}
```

My question is, how do I specify the jni method signature of a generic class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javah` seems to ignore generics:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Base_nativeDoSomething
   (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm late here, but I'll add it for future references.

Generics in Java are implemented using [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which basically is: generics exists only in *compile-time*: they are gone after that, not existing in *run-time*.

This means that, even though you can have a method like `public native void blah(E genericOne, F genericTwo)`, when compiled, it is actually converted to `public native void blah(Object genericOne, Object genericTwo)`.

This way, you don't need to even care about generics when using the Java Native Interface: everything is converted down to `Object`, so you can simply reference them as a `jobject`.

The same goes for the Java classes: you can simply reference them as a `jclass`.

Answer (score 0):

With `javah`. Don't try to figure it out yourself when there's a tool that does it for youl.

Comment: As mentioned above, javah appears to ignore generics.

Comment: @MM So the implication is therefore that generics do not form part of native method signatures, which is what the other answers here also say.